# Can I access NATnetwork VMs via SSH?

Tags: windows, virtualbox

[image]

There seems to be no option of port forwarding for this use case. That's why I am asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but the "Port Forwarding" option is found in the network's **global** configuration in the 'Tools' section – it is not per-VM because the network itself is not unique per VM either. (Unlike the default "NAT" mode, if you put two VMs in the same "NAT network" they'll be able to see each other directly.)